# Pass the value of a variable from one page to another in php

Tags: php, variables

I'm working with php and facing the following problem:

```
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
echo "Transaction Result: " . $result . "<br><br>";
```

I want to transfer the value of `$result` to a new page there I want to print the value of this.

I know how to pass the values of constants from one page to another through `$_POST['']`, 
but when I try the same with `$variable` that does not workout the way.

Comment: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this is to use PHP sessions. When a session is started, PHP automatically sends a cookie to the user that tracks him. Every page that that user visits from then on will have a special variable called `$_SESSION[]` that stores variables that can be accessed from any page on the server.

More information about this topic can be found in the [PHP Manual: Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: the value of    `$result` is obtained when the script is loaded.
and i want the value after loading should print in another page.
i tried session
it was like   `<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['result']=$result;
 ?>`

and the page on which it would post have codes like
      ` <?php
  session_start();
  
         echo $_SESSION['result'];
?>`

Comment: am I making any mistake in syntax??

Comment: Could you describe what happened when you tried using sessions?

Comment: in the page where the actual variable available
    `<header>
    <?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['result']=$result;
 ?>
</header>`

the page where i need to inherit
    `<header>
    <?php
  session_start();
  $res=$_SESSION['result'];
  ?>
</header>
<body><?php
  echo $res;
  ?>
</body>`